# How do I generate the correct TOTP with Node with correct Headers and SHA512 hashed Token?

Tags: node.js, https, http-headers, hmac, totp

A recent school project I was assigned has a coding challenge we have to complete. The challenge has multiple parts, and the final part is uploading to a private GitHub repo and submitting a completion request by making a POST request under certain conditions.

I have successfully completed the other parts of the challenge and am stuck on submitting the request. The submission has to follow these rules:

> **Build your solution request**
>
> First, construct a JSON string like below:
>
> `{`
>
> `"github_url": "https://github.com/YOUR_ACCOUNT/GITHUB_REPOSITORY",`
>
> `"contact_email": "YOUR_EMAIL"`
>
> `}`
>
> Fill in your email address for `YOUR_EMAIL`, and the private Github repository with your solution in `YOUR_ACCOUNT/GITHUB_REPOSITORY`.
>   Then, make an HTTP POST request to the following URL with the JSON string as the body part.
>
> `CHALLENGE_URL`
>
> **Content type**
>
> The Content-Type: of the request must be `application/json`.
>
> **Authorization**
>
> The URL is protected by HTTP Basic Authentication, which is explained on Chapter 2 of RFC2617, so you have to provide an Authorization: header field in your POST request.
>
> - For the userid of HTTP Basic Authentication, use the same email address you put in the JSON string.
> - For the password , provide a 10-digit time-based one time password conforming to RFC6238
>     TOTP.
>
> **Authorization password**
>
> For generating the TOTP password, you will need to use the following setup:
>
> - You have to generate a correct TOTP password according to RFC6238
> - TOTP's `Time Step X` is 30 seconds. `T0` is 0.
> - Use `HMAC-SHA-512` for the hash function, instead of the default `HMAC-SHA-1`.
> - Token shared secret is the userid followed by ASCII string value `"APICHALLENGE"` (not including double quotations).
>
> **Shared secret examples**
>
> For example, if the userid is `"email@example.com"`, the token shared secret is `"email@example.comAPICHALLENGE"` (without quotes).
>
> If your POST request succeeds, the server returns HTTP status code 200 .

I have tried to follow this outline **very** carefully, and testing my work in different ways. However, it seems I can't get it right. We are supposed to make the request from a Node server backend. This is what I have done so far. I created a new npm project with `npm init` and installed the dependencies you will see in the code below:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const base64 = require('base-64');
const utf8 = require('utf8');

const { totp } = require('otplib');


const reqJSON = 
{
    github_url: GITHUB_URL,
    contact_email: MY_EMAIL
}
const stringData = JSON.stringify(reqJSON);

const URL = CHALLENGE_URL;
const sharedSecret = reqJSON.contact_email + "APICHALLENGE";

totp.options = { digits: 10, algorithm: "sha512" }

const myTotp = totp.generate(sharedSecret);
const isValid = totp.check(myTotp, sharedSecret);

console.log("Token Info:", {myTotp, isValid});




const authStringUTF = reqJSON.contact_email + ":" + myTotp;
const bytes = utf8.encode(authStringUTF);
const encoded = base64.encode(bytes);



const createReq = async () =>
{

    try 
    {

        // set the headers
        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Authorization": "Basic " + encoded
            }
        };

        console.log("Making req", {URL, reqJSON, config});

        const res = await axios.post(URL, stringData, config);
        console.log(res.data);
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        console.error(err.response.data);
    }
};

createReq();
```

As far as I understand, I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake. I have tried to be very careful in my understanding of the requirements. I have briefly looked into all of the documents the challenge outlines, and gathered the necessary requirements needed to correctly generate a TOTP under the given conditions.

I have found the npm package `otplib` can satisfy these requirements with the options I have passed in.

However, my solution is incorrect. When I try to submit my solution, I get the error message, `"Invalid token, wrong code"`. Can someone please help me see what I'm doing wrong?

I really don't want all my hard work to be for nothing, as this was a lengthy project.

Thank you so much in advance for your time and help on this. I am very grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Readme of the package `otplib` states:

```
// TOTP defaults
{
  // ...includes all HOTP defaults
  createHmacKey: totpCreateHmacKey,
  epoch: Date.now(),
  step: 30,
  window: 0,
}
```

So the default value for `epoch (T0)` is `Date.now()` which is the RFC standard. The task description defines that `T0` is `0`.

You need to change the default value for `epoch` to `0`:

```
totp.options = { digits: 10, algorithm: "sha512", epoch: 0 }
```